# How can I get the data from a thread that acts as a UDP server?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, datagram

I am making an Android application that receives messages from an Arduino, I implemented a UDP server opening a Thread, but I can not get the value of the answer string "lastMessage", because with this value I will make a series of actions.

This is my class served_UDP:

```
public class Servidor_UDP {
    private boolean server_activado = true;
    private String lastMessage = "";
    DatagramSocket socket;
    private byte[] resp;
    private DatagramPacket pqtResp;
    Servidor_UDP()
    {
        resp = new byte[1024];
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(6000);
            pqtResp = new DatagramPacket(resp, resp.length);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        Thread t = new Thread(new server());
        t.start();
    }

    public class server implements Runnable {
        server() { run(); }
        public void run() {
            String message = "";
            try {
                do
                {
                    socket.receive(pqtResp);
                    //message = new String(resp).trim();
                    message = new String(pqtResp.getData(),0,pqtResp.getLength());
                    lastMessage = message;
                } while(server_activado);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getString() 
    {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void setServer(boolean b)
    {
        server_activado = b;
    }
}
```

This class I implemented from the onCreate of my MainActivity:

```
Servidor_UDP UDP_S;
UDP_S = new Servidor_UDP();
UDP_S.start();
```

I try to get the results of a method of the main class and show them in a TextView to make sure that the messages are arriving but it does not show me anything, just empty.

```
public void actualizarUI()
{
    respuesta = UDP_S.getString();
    txt.setText(respuesta);
}
```

I await your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `server()` constructor should not call `run()`. `Thread.start()` will do that. At present `Thread.start()` is never executing, let alone completing, so any code that calls your `start()` method will never return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I deleted the server runnable class, and implement run() method directly on the thread, but it doesn't have return. Why the thread isn't completing?

Comment: Why didn't you try just deleting the `run()` call in the constructor? As per this answer? Nothing else necessary.  What exactly is the point of asking the question if you don't try the answers?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The other answer is right!

Ok so, I think you have the problem when creating the new server()...

You could try this:

```
private server server;
public void start(){
    server = new server();
    Thread t = new Thread(server);
    t.start();
}

public class server implements Runnable {
    server() { /*NO run();*/ }
    public void run() {
        String message = "";
        try {
            do
            {
                socket.receive(pqtResp);
                //message = new String(resp).trim();
                message = new String(pqtResp.getData(),0,pqtResp.getLength());
                lastMessage = message;
            } while(server_activado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }
}

public String getString()
{
    return server.getLastMessage();
}
```

You are doing new server(); so I you are creating a new object, you should save it in a class variable like I did, and then create a get method in the server class...

PD: Intenta no hacer codigo en castellano :)

Comment: This has exactly the same problem that is pointed out in the other answer which you state to be correct. `new server()` never returns, so `Thread.start()` never executes, so the OP's `start()` method never returns.

Comment: @EJP, the OP commented it works for him, having hate for my answer is not the correct way. Also, I am saying your answer is right. Where is the problem on having 2 useful answers instead of one?